# How to read data from Firebase Database to Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to read data from my firebase database I have added  Firebase Admin SDK V 5.0 and i have try the following

```
 $factory = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount(__DIR__.'/Firebase.json');

    $database = $factory->createDatabase();
    $reference = $database->getReference('users-dev');

    $snapshot = $reference->getSnapshot();

    $value = $snapshot->getValue();
    
    dd($value);
```

and I got this
[image]

And on Firebase data are like
[image]

Comment: It looks like no data exists at `users-dev` in the database you connected to. Can you show why this would not be the correct result?

Comment: Sorry for the delay on response, And I have to edit the question and users-dev have a record like it is shown on the question

Answer (score 0):

Your code is connecting to the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database), while the screenshot shows [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore). While both databases are part of Firebase, they're completely separate, and the API for one won't work with the other.

You'll either have to model the data in the Realtime Database, or use the [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cloud-firestore.html) plugin from the same PHP library.